# How to import 'org.hamcrest.collection' in junit to test collection methods

Tags: assertion

I am using Junit 5 and getting the following error while importing collection packages

> The import org.hamcrest.collection cannot be resolved

I need to validate assertThat method & hasSize() from collection for which the below import should be done.

```
import org.hamcrest.collection.IsEmptyCollection;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PortJUnit {

    PortBO portBO;
    ArrayList<Port> list = new ArrayList<Port>();
    @Before
    public void createObjectForPort()
    {
        portBO = new PortBO();
    }
    @Test
    public void testPortDetails()
    {       
        list.add(new Port(101,"abc","cbe"));
        list.add(new Port(102,"abd","chennai"));
        list.add(new Port(103,"abe","bangalore"));
        list.add(new Port(104,"abf","mumbai"));
        list.add(new Port(105,"abg","delhi"));
        String detail = "107,abh,Toronto";  
        portBO.addElementAtSpecfiedPosition(list, 6, detail);   
        assertThat(list, hasSize(6));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use hamcrest-core dependency.

Please try to use instead - `hamcrest-all-1.3.jar` and your problem will be solved.